# Python - Use decorated function in class

Tags: python, flask, decorator

The parameters of my decorated function are getting swapped.
In `authorized(self, resp)`, `resp` is becoming a `ClientView` object and `self` is becoming a `resp` variable.
How can I decorate this function so it can be used as a method?

It uses flask class view and flask_oauthlib.

Function code:

```
class ClientView(UserView):

    @bp.route('/vklogin/authorized')
    @vk.authorized_handler
    def authorized(self, resp):
        if resp is None:
            return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
                request.args['error_reason'],
                request.args['error_description']
            )
        session['oauth_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
        me = self.vk.get('method/users.get?uids={}'.format(resp['user_id']))
        return '{}'.format(me.data)
```

Decorator function code:

```
class OAuthRemoteApp(object):
    def authorized_handler(self, f):
            @wraps(f)
            def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
                if 'oauth_verifier' in request.args:
                    try:
                        data = self.handle_oauth1_response()
                    except OAuthException as e:
                        data = e
                elif 'code' in request.args:
                    try:
                        data = self.handle_oauth2_response()
                    except OAuthException as e:
                        data = e
                else:
                    data = self.handle_unknown_response()

                # free request token
                session.pop('%s_oauthtok' % self.name, None)
                session.pop('%s_oauthredir' % self.name, None)
                return f(*((data,) + args), **kwargs)
            return decorated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this simplied (and runnable) version code of your code:

```
class OAuthRemoteApp(object):
    def authorized_handler(self, f):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            print(self, f, args, kwargs)   #1
            # (<__main__.OAuthRemoteApp object at 0xb74d324c>, <function authorized at 0xb774ba04>, (<__main__.ClientView object at 0xb74d32cc>,), {})
            data = 'resp'
            print((data,) + args)  #2
            # ('resp', <__main__.ClientView object at 0xb74d32cc>)
            return f(*((data,) + args), **kwargs)             
        return decorated

vk = OAuthRemoteApp()

class ClientView(object):
    @vk.authorized_handler
    def authorized(self, resp):
        print(self, resp)  #3
        # ('resp', <__main__.ClientView object at 0xb7452eec>)
cv = ClientView()
cv.authorized()
```

1. Notice that the first item in `args` is the `ClientView` instance:

   ```
   args = (<__main__.ClientView object at 0xb74d32cc>,)
   ```
2. The expression `(data,) + args` prepends `'resp'` in front of the
   `ClientView` instance. This is the source of the problem.
3. Notice that here `self` is `resp` and `resp` is the `ClientView`
   instance. The arguments are being supplied in the wrong order.

One way to fix the problem is to insert `data` *after* the first item
in `args`:

```
class OAuthRemoteApp(object):
    def authorized_handler(self, f):
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            data = 'resp'
            args = args[:1] + (data,) + args[1:]
            return f(*args, **kwargs) 
        return decorated

vk = OAuthRemoteApp()

class ClientView(object):
    @vk.authorized_handler
    def authorized(self, resp):
        print(self, resp)

cv = ClientView()
cv.authorized()
```

yields

```
(<__main__.ClientView object at 0xb7434f0c>, 'resp')
```

which shows the `ClientView` and `resp` arguments being supplied in the correct order.